# Live template shortcut for == intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

My plain question is, whether by default is there a live template which can be used for `==` in intellij?

If yes, what?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Type something else to get `==`? Or press a key combo to insert it?

Comment: @Koyasha yes, i want to know whether its possible to use a '.' based operation (ex. myObject.E and press Enter upon suggestion, hope you get what i mean ) which would generate <space>==<space> for me, so that I don't need to manually type a space and two equal signs and another space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default postfix template for it, but you can add a custom one in the **File | Settings | Editor | General | Postfix Completion** dialog.

You can also type `myObject==<value>` and hit `Ctrl+Alt+L` right after that to auto-fix the format of your code, which means spaces will be added automatically to make it `myObject == <value>`. It'll save you extra trouble.

[image]